# Can we Call Animated.Timing() after server response?

Tags: react-native, animation

I have one task of using the Animation library in react-native to display the components in specific manner. Now for static screens (where there is no server request), I found it easy to implement since I use to initiate the Animation.Timing() function in the componentWillMount class and the render method I would use the style to include the animation in the Animated.View.

But when I use the same logic in a screen where data is first received from the server and then display them in the animated format. There this logic fails as the Animated.Timing() call is made during the initiation of the class itself (componentWillMount).

So how can we do that is a real confusion for me. Need some guiding on it.

I have used redux to get the data from the server. So in a nutshell I am giving a snippet of the code. Can anyone help me to understand where exactly I should call the Animated.Timing() method

```
    componentDidMount(){
      this.requestServerforData();
    }
    UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
        
        //**Change the opacity from 0 to 1 when the server request completes**

        this.visibility = new Animated.Value(0);
        Animated.timing(this.visibility,{
            toValue:1,
            duration:800,
            delay:800,
            useNativeDriver:false
        }).start();
    }

   render(){

       return(
            
                {(this.props.dashboard) ?   // I tried this also not working 
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={{marginTop:30}}>
                    
                    
                <Animated.View style={{opacity:this.visibility}}>
                    
                    <View style={styles.GreenTipBackground}>

                    </View>
                </Animated.View>
               </ScrollView> : null }
   }

 const mapstatetoProps = state =>{

    return {  
        dashboard:state.appData.dashboard,
      
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is `requestServerforData` doing? Post the code?

Comment: Its requesting the server for the data... in the redux thunk. Once I receive the data , the mapstatetoProps is called to display that data in the screen. I have shared that

Comment: You could use `componentDidUpate` and check for the changes in Dashboard and start your animation there. `componentWillMount` happens before `componentDidMount` and is not the place you want to be doing animation stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the JS `Promise` API like this:

```js
const { Component } = require("react");
const { Animated } = require("react-native");

class SomeComponent extends Component {
    visibility = new Animated.Value(0);

    async componentDidMount() {
        // The code below will only run after `this.requestServerForData` has completed
        await this.requestServerForData();

        Animated.timing(this.visibility, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 800,
            delay: 800,
            useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
    }

    requestServerForData = async () => {
        // Do some asynchronous data fetching things
    };

    render() {
        // return ... your UI
    }
}
```